# Drupal-based SQL query through PHP: count t1 join t2

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, join

I have two tables like so:

```
table {node}
`nid`, `uid`, `type`
 1    1   basketball
 2    1   basketball
 3    1   football
 4    2   football
 5    2   basketball

table {strato_ticket}
`tid`, `author_uid`, `purpose`, `active`
 1      1   'Ticket to a basketball game' TRUE
 2      1   'Ticket to a football game'   TRUE
 3      2   'Ticket to a football game'   FALSE
```

I'd like to generate a report that counts the number of each kind of node, and then counts the number of active tickets that each user has associated with that kind of node.

My solution uses a combination of SQL and PHP: I have a PHP loop for each kind of node that I'm interested in, which simplifies the SQL query, and translates from 'type' to 'purpose', eg

```
$node_types = array('basketball', 'football');
foreach($node_types as $node){
  switch($type){
    case 'basketball':
      $purpose = array('Ticket to a basketball node');
      break;
    case 'football':
      $purpose = array('Ticket to a football game');
      break;
  }
  $where = " WHERE ({strato_ticket}.`purpose` = '"
    .implode("' OR {strato_ticket}.`purpose` = '",$purpose)."')";
```

Finally I have the trouble spot, the SQL query. When I was just counting nodes owned by each user, it worked fine:

```
$query = "
      SELECT uid, count( * ) AS nodes_owned
      FROM {node} WHERE `type` = '$type'
      GROUP BY uid ORDER BY nodes_owned DESC
      ";
  $query = db_query($query);

output:
Now displaying info for basketball.
uid nodes_owned
 1       2
 2       1
Now displaying info for football.
uid nodes_owned
 1       1
 2       1
```

But now that I need to query against another table, strato_ticket, things get complicated, and my query is returning FALSE without throwing an error (I think).

```
 $query = "
    SELECT count(*) as tickets
    FROM {strato_ticket} INNER JOIN (
        SELECT node.uid, count( * ) AS nodes_owned
        FROM {node} WHERE `type` = '$type'
        GROUP BY uid
      ) AS {nodecount}
      ON {strato_ticket}.`author_uid` = {nodecount}.`uid`
      $where
      GROUP BY nodecount.uid ORDER BY nodecount.nodes_owned DESC
      ";
  $query = db_query($query);
```

I'm not very good with SQL and I'm not quite sure how it's broken. Could use a little help?

Ideally would like to see

```
uid nodes_owned tickets
//basketball
 1       2        1
 2       1        0
//football 
 1       1        1
 2       1        0
```

Comment: I would suggest testing your query out in the MySQL console (where errors will be immediately obvious to you), then reviewing the Drupal docs for guidance on correctly writing your SQL for db_query(). I don't think you want the curlies around {nodecount} above.

Comment: For best DB practice in Drupal, use DB placeholders (eg %s in place of $type, and rewriting your $where construct to do same).

Comment: Also, don't use \`, that is mysql specific and unecessary unless are using reserved words for your columns. Using aliases should make it easier too: `{strato_ticket} st` and then just `st.autor_uid`. And as Chris already said, use %s placeholders (important for security! not just best practice) and the {} are only necessary for tables maintained by Drupal (for example, if you're using a database prefix name). Don't use it for aliases or external tables.

Comment: No idea what you mean, `select type from node limit 10;` works perfectly fine. It is also not listed on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html. It is listed on http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html but as non-reserved word. And even then, alias.column should imho work fine. Aliasing table names is not necessary but *very* common in Drupal, exactly because you otherwise end up with very long column identifiers like in your code.

Comment: Also, I suggest to use placeholders also for cases like this. In fact, you should use db_placeholders and an IN condition like this: `st.purpose IN (" . db_placeholders($purpose, 'varchar') . '")`. and then pass $purpose in as arguments. Again much shorter than your code and in Drupal 7, you only need a single placeholder: `st.purpose IN (:purposes)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the placeholders, which I can get to later, I think this solves it.

```
$form = array();
$node_types = array('basketball','football');
// if($user->uid == 1){
  $form[$type][] = array('#value'=>"Showing how many of each node type each user owns.".'<br/>');
  foreach($node_types as $type){
  // Count the number of nodes each user owns of $type.
  $form[$type][] = array('#value'=>"Now displaying info for $type".'s. <br/>');
  switch($type){
    case 'basketball':
      $purpose = array('ticket to a basketball game', 'basketball');
    break;
    case 'football':
      $purpose = array('ticket to a football game');
    break;
  }
  $purpose = implode("', '", $purpose);
  //@todo : Make a temporary table to query against so I'm not hitting node table multiple times.
  $ticketquery = "
    SELECT author_uid, purpose, COUNT( * ) AS invitees_accepted
    FROM {strato_ticket}
    WHERE purpose IN ('$purpose')
    GROUP BY author_uid, `purpose`
  ";
  $nodequery = "
    SELECT node.uid, count( * ) AS nodes_owned, type
    FROM {node}
    WHERE `type` IN ('$type')
    GROUP BY uid, type";
  $query = "
    SELECT * FROM
    ($nodequery) AS nt
    JOIN
    ($ticketquery) AS tt
    ON nt.uid = tt.author_uid
    GROUP BY nt.uid ORDER BY nt.nodes_owned DESC
   ";

  drupal_set_message('Query is <br/>'.$query);
  //return;
  $query = db_query($query);
  $first = true;
  while ($rec = db_fetch_object($query)){
    if($first){
      $form[$type][] = array('#value'=>"And the winner is: ".print_r($rec, true).'<br/>');
      $first = false;
    }
    else {
     $form[$type][] = array('#value'=>print_r($rec, true).'<br/>');
    }
  }
 // }
}
```